# Using gWidgetsWWW2 with googleVis

Tags: r, googlevis, gwidgets, r-rook-package

How can one go about using `googleVis` charts with `gWidgetsWWW2`? I have seen that it is possible to use `googleVis` with `Rook` (http://www.magesblog.com/2012/08/rook-rocks-example-with-googlevis.html and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis.pdf) but I have not found any example of using `googleVis` with `gWidgetsWWW2`. My initial try:

```
require(gWidgetsWWW2)
require(googleVis)
w <- gwindow("hello")
sb <- gstatusbar("Powered by gWidgetsWWW and Rook", cont=w)
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", timevar="Year")
ghtml(M$html, cont = g) # Trying html only
```

I end up seeing the following when I `gwidgetsWWW2::load_app()`:

[image]

I've tried decomposing the html into its header, chart and footer also but this didn't work either:

```
 # ghtml(M$html$header, cont = g) # Trying header only
 # ghtml(M$html$chart, cont = g) # Trying chart
 # ghtml(M$html$footer, cont = g) # Trying footer only
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Also, if there isn't a `gWidget` that will directly allow the use of `googleVis` charts, is it possible to integrate `Rook` code (e.g. the code given at http://www.magesblog.com/2012/08/rook-rocks-example-with-googlevis.html) with the `gWidgetWWW2` code? If so, how can I go about doing this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a good question, and unfortunately I don't have a good answer. I tried decomposing the results, passing some javascript through some internal functions (`add_js_queue`) and still no luck. I got closest to rendering this by writing the output to a file then using `ghtml` to load the file from a url. I even tried wrapping in an iframe. But sadly this didn't work either. If you persist and figure something out, it would be a nice addition.

Comment: @jverzani, thanks for looking into this. If I do figure it out, I will let you know. Thank you (and thanks for an excellent set of gWidgets packages).